# Find and replace many factors in one column in R

Tags: r, if-statement, grepl

I have column with 32 different levels. I need to replace these levels

```
 ?
 diet
 diet contr
 IDDM
 Note
 Other
 denial
 Resolved
 Unsure
```

in that column to **No**

I know I can do this using a massive ifelse((column = "?" | column = "diet" |.....) statement, i was wondering if there is an efficient way to do replace these bag of factors ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `%in%`, along with `levels()` and the `levels<-` replacement function. For example, with the sample vector `x`

```
( x <- factor(c("diet", "diet contr", "IDDM", "Note", "Other", 
      "denial", "Resolved", "Unsure")) )
# [1] diet       diet contr IDDM       Note       Other     
# [6] denial     Resolved   Unsure    
# 8 Levels: denial diet diet contr IDDM Note ... Unsure
```

to change "diet", "Note", and "Other" all to "No" you can change their respective levels with

```
levels(x)[levels(x) %in% c("diet", "Note", "Other")] <- "No"
x
# [1] No         diet contr IDDM       No         No        
# [6] denial     Resolved   Unsure    
# Levels: denial No diet contr IDDM Resolved Unsure
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `mapvalues` function from the `plyr` package.  Try this code snippet, which assumes that you have a factor column in a data frame called `df$column`:

```
library(plyr)
vals_to_replace <- c("diet", "diet contr", "IDDM")
mapvalues(df$column,
          from = vals_to_replace,
          to = rep("No", length(vals_to_replace)))
```

You can add as many factor names to `vals_to_replace` as you like.